# Mac Numbers equivalent to Microsoft Excel's Control+Arrow Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: ms-office, numbers

Is there a feature in the `MacOS Numbers` application that allows me to jump to non-empty cells? In Excel if I hold the control key and press any of the keys <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> the cursor will navigate to the next non empty cell in that direction from the currently selected cell or hit the outer boundaries of the spreadsheet if all the remaining cells in that direction are empty.

Is there some analogous operation I can do in Numbers that's equivalent?

Comment: Just realized this was a dupe https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208916/numbers-shortcut-to-select-next-non-empty-cell

Comment: Unfortunately that question has no answers so we cannot close this as a duplicate,

Comment: Answered here → [macos - Numbers shortcut to select next non-empty cell - Ask Different_2019-09-25](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370899/347592)